# facing with an error: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt" while calculating distance-matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance-matrix, scipy-spatial

I have generated a matrix randomly with:`mtx=numpy.random.rand(100,3)`
then I tried to reduce the dimension of matrix to 2 using:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
newMTX=TSNE(2,method='barnes_hut')
```

After that I wanted to calculate the euclidean-distance matrix of `newMTX`, then I did:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
dis=distance_matrix(newMTX,newMTX)
```

But I faced an ERROR (`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt`) which I can not unterstand the reason for. can anyone help me whith that?

I already tried:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances as distance_matrix
dis=distance_matrix(newMTX,newMTX)
```

but I faced the same error.

I searched and found another solution as alternative:

```py
    dist = lambda p1, p2: numpy.sqrt(((p1-p2)**2).sum())
    dm = numpyp.asarray([[dist(p1, p2) for p2 in newMTX] for p1 in newMTX])
```

but I am not sure whether it is an efficient solution to calculate a distance-Matrix of large matrix e.g. a 1000000*2-matrix?

What I want to achive is a 100*100 euclidean-distance-matrix of 100*2 matrix `newMTX`

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: I used ```from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist``` and  ```cdist(newMTX,newMTX,"euclidean")``` it workes but id can not understand the different between this and ```from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix```!!!

Comment: Could you print **newMTX** ?